# bash read: group read results by timeout

Tags: linux, bash, inotifywait

Short story: On my Linux desktop, I want for notifications whenever nodes under `/dev` are created or deleted (it's really useful to know what nodes are created when I plug some device in). I wrote two naive scripts for that:

The first one writes these changes to the log file by means of `inotifywait`:

```
#!/bin/sh

inotifywait -m -e create,delete --timefmt '%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S' --format '[%T] %e %w%f' /dev > /var/log/devdir_changes
```

Resulting log file looks like this:

```
[2014.08.19-01:32:51] CREATE /dev/vcs63
[2014.08.19-01:32:51] CREATE /dev/vcsa63
```

And the second script that monitors that log file (with bash `read` command) and shows notifications:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do

   # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # Now, listen for new messages
   echo "listening for new messages.."

   tail -f -n 0 /var/log/devdir_changes | \
      while read time type message; do
         notify-send "$type" "$message"
      done

      echo "restarting in 5 seconds.."
      sleep 5
      echo "restarting.."
done

echo "exiting."
```

It works, but, as expected, there is dedicated notification balloon for each created/removed node. Usually there are several nodes when I plug single USB device, sometimes really a lot of them. So, when new entry is detected, I'd wait for some time (say, 200-300 ms) for more entries, and only after timeout after last received entry, cry collected entries with `notify-send`.

I'm not experienced bash programmer (and linux user), so I'd be glad if someone give me some clue on how to implement this **correctly**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too experienced with bash but I think you could feed tail's output to a while loop like in the following bash script:

```
#/bin/bash

# maximum time between records to be grouped
# in seconds, e.g. "0.300" for 300ms
#TIMEOUT=0.300
TIMEOUT=3.1

# maximum number of records to be grouped
LIMIT=100

LINE_BREAK=$'\n'

# tail -f -n 0 /var/log/devdir_changes | \
while true
do
    declare -a times types messages

    # wait for, read and store first record
    read time type message
    times[0]="$time"
    types[0]="$type"
    messages[0]="$message"
    size=1

    # wait for more records to appear within timeout
    while [ $size -lt "$LIMIT" ]
    do
        read -t "$TIMEOUT" time type message || break
        times[$size]="$time"
        types[$size]="$type"
        messages[$size]="$message"
        size=$((${size} + 1))
    done

    # build message from record group
    message="${types[0]} ${messages[0]}"
    i=1
    while [ $i -lt $size ]
    do
        message="$message$LINE_BREAK${types[$i]} ${messages[$i]}"
        i=$((i + 1))
    done

    # send message as notification
    echo "$message"
    # notify-send "$message"
done
```

The key is using a timeout (-t 3.1) in the call to read and buffering input (in arrays) until either a timeout is reached or the buffer "is full" (limit 100 in example). The timeout is given in seconds, use 0.3 for 300ms.

(Edit 1: some comments, no timeout for first record)

---

Edit 2: In order to make grouping of lines by time of availability more reusable you could use a function:

```
# group lines which get available at the same time
#
# This can be used to group lines from asynchronous input
# according to (sufficiently large) time gaps between lines.
#
# $1 = max seconds to wait for another line; default: 1.5
# $2 = max number of lines to read; default: 10
# $3 = group terminator to use; default: $'\0'
function time_group_lines() {
    local timeout="${1:-1.5}"
    local limit="${2:-10}"
    local terminator="${3}"
    local line
    while true ; do
        read line || return 0
        echo "$line"
        size=1
        while [ $size -lt "$limit" ] ; do
            read -t "$timeout" line || break
            echo "$line"
            size=$(($size + 1))
        done
        if [ -z "$terminator" ]
        then echo -n -e "\x00"
        else echo -n "$terminator"
        fi
    done
}

# tail -f -n 0 /var/log/devdir_changes | \
# sed 's/^[^ ]* //' \
time_group_lines "$TIMEOUT" "$LIMIT" | \
while true ; do
    read -d $'\0' group || break
    # notify-send "$group"
    echo -e "$group"
done
```